# Ban user with id

Tags: javascript, discord.js

this code guarantees the staff to ban the user by tagging. But I wish it could be done with id, even when the user exits. 
How can I also add the option to ban a user when he is no longer in the discord? With his id. 
So even if it exits the server i can ban it, currently the bot only bans if you mention the user and check with the ticks. Can it be integrated? Could anyone be kind to help me? Thanks in advance :))

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know someone can't be banned if he is not in the server (guild) anymore, if you mean that.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done one of two ways,
you can send a message like this <@USERID> and right click and ban the user,
Or, if you want the bot to do it for you, i'm not sure if you can ban a user if they are not in the server using a bot. So, if not, you can use an array with the users ID. Upon joining the server, check if the users ID is in said array, and if so, ban the user and remove the ID from the array.